# Is there some kind of functionality, where a pointer dereference gives an rvalue?

Tags: c++

Is there some kind of functionality, where a pointer dereference gives an rvalue?

So, a usual pointer gives an lvalue:

```
Foo *p = ...;

fn(p[42]);    // p[42] is an lvalue
```

I'd like to have `p[42]` return an rvalue, so a `fn(Foo &&)` can be called for `fn(p[42])`:

```
<some_pointer_type> p = ...;

fn(p[42]);    // I'd like to have p[42] be an rvalue, so an fn(Foo &&) would be called
```

Note: I'd like to have `p` has this functionality, the **pointer type** should have this information, that dereferencing it should give an rvalue.

Comment: What about `std::move()`?

Comment: If `p` was an object of a class with overloaded `operator*` you could make it work like that.

Comment: So you want a custom type with an `operator*()` that returns an rvalue?

Comment: @underscore_d: yes, it can be done with a custom template pointer class. My question is there already something like this?

Comment: Your'e asking for a tool or library?

Comment: @StoryTeller: basically I'm interested in a core language feature, or in the standard library (I'm not familiar with new C++ features, maybe there's something like this). If this problem isn't covered in the standard, then I'll create a custom pointer template class for this.

Comment: Well, you can always inherit from `std::experimental::observer_ptr` to have all the basic smart pointer stuff. Then just overload/hide `operator*` to return  `std::add_rvalue_reference_t` instead.

Comment: The standard likes code like `f(*p); g(*p);` to do what is expected. It is expected that `f` and `g` will get the same argument. You want one to get an rvalue reference and the other to get a moved-from object. That is weird and surprising. You will have to manually request the second behavior which is already supported with `f(std::move(*p)); g(*p);`.

Comment: @nwp: I don't understand your example. `p` should have this information. It would mean that `p` points to an object (or an array of objects), that it should be moved from. I'd like to avoid creating a lot of duplicate functions (one for the copy, and one for the move case - their code would be copy-paste, except the `std::move`'s).

Comment: if your pointer type models an iterator too (as it seems), you might use std::move_iterator<>

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: thanks, I didn't know `std::move_iterator` existed. This is the closest thing I need so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By means of `std::move()` you can perform an *unconditional* cast to a *rvalue*.

```
fn(std::move(p[42]));
```

The name `move` is actually misleading here: nothing is being moved, but a cast is being performed.

---

Consider then writing a pointer template `Ptr` whose operators `*` and `[]` are overloaded to return a rvalue:

```
#include <utility>

class Foo {};

template<typename T>
class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr(T* ptr): ptr_{ptr} {}
    T&& operator*() { return std::move(*ptr_); }
    T&& operator[](int idx) { return std::move(*(ptr_ + idx)); }
private:
    T* ptr_;
};

void fn(Foo&& x) { return; }
void fn(const Foo& x) { return; }

int main()
{
    Foo foo[50];
    Ptr<Foo> p{&foo[0]};

    // call void fn(Foo&&)
    fn(p[42]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll implement something like this, if there's no other solution already in the language.

Answer (score 0):

The type of result of pointer dereferencing, that is type result of some overloaded operator can not depend of some information stored at pointer object at runtime because its signature is defined at compile-time. However it possible to overload operator based on pointer origin:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename TItems>
class t_FancyPointer;

template<typename TItems>
class t_FancyPointer<TItems[]>
{
    private: TItems * m_p_items;

    public: explicit
    t_FancyPointer(TItems * p_items) : m_p_items{p_items} {}

    public: TItems &
    operator [](::std::size_t const index) &
    {
        return(m_p_items[index]);
    }

    public: TItems &&
    operator [](::std::size_t const index) &&
    {
        return(::std::move(m_p_items[index]));
    }
};

void
fn(::std::string &&)
{
    ::std::cout << "rvalue reference" << ::std::endl;
}

void
fn(::std::string &)
{
    ::std::cout << "lvalue reference" << ::std::endl;
}

::std::string items[4];
t_FancyPointer<::std::string[]> perma_storage{items};

t_FancyPointer<::std::string[]> &
Get_PermaStorage(void)
{
    return(perma_storage);
}

t_FancyPointer<::std::string[]>
Get_TempStorage(void)
{
    return(t_FancyPointer<::std::string[]>{items});
}

int main()
{
    // calls fn(::std::string &)
    fn(Get_PermaStorage()[42]);
    // calls fn(::std::string &&)
    fn(Get_TempStorage()[42]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
lvalue reference
rvalue reference
```

If you just want to always return && then you can define a single operator [] returning an rvalue reference:

```
public: TItems &&
operator [](::std::size_t const index)
{
    return(::std::move(m_p_items[index]));
}
```

Though I have no idea why would you do something like this.

Comment: I need this feature in compile-time, not run-time. Massimiliano Janes told in the comments that there's something like this already in the library, called `std::move_iterator`. I think the intention of this is the same as mine. I'd like to avoid duplicate functions.